# Single word to denote date and time

Tags: synonyms

I want one word that means Date and Time. For example in "the date and time of the event will be announced later" I want to use single word instead of "date and time"

Answer (score 14):

Just saying "date" should be sufficient:

> The date of the event will be announced later.

In this usage, "date" implies time as well -- if the organizer of the event hasn't even determined the particular date yet, the exact time of day is probably up in the air as well. Another example: when you agree on a date and time to meet someone or do something with someone, you're often said to "make a date" or "have a date," and it's understood that that means the time as well as the day.

Similarly, "time" can imply date, as in:

> I remember the time we went camping and Dad swallowed a bug!

In that sense, the speaker is referring to something that happened on a particular date and time, but the specific date and time are less important than the thing that happened.

On the other hand, sometimes you want to identify a particular instant that something happened. For that case, "moment" is a good word, as is the phrase "point in time":

> The world changed the moment Armstrong set foot on the moon.

Comment: Both 'point in time' and 'moment' suggest short duration.

Comment: @user93422, true, but "date and time" also identifies a particular minute or even second. For the purpose you described, I think "date" is the best option.

Comment: @user93422: I seriously doubt you'll get a better word than *moment* for the general-purpose word you seem to seek. Caleb is right that for your example context, *Date* would imply *Time* (though in some other contexts, *Time* can imply *Date*). In my programming days I used variables called **xxx_dttm**, which I personally always thought of as **Date/TimeStamp of event xxx**.

Answer (score 6):

In technical writing where precision is necessary, the term *datetime* has been coined when it is necessary to be precise that date **and** time are to be specified. This is particularly common in documentation of computer systems and databases.

I have never, however, seen this term used in a non-technical setting (that I can recall).

Comment: For a technical example, see http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html which mentions e.g. *the current date-time*..

Comment: Or [Python's datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use *details*. You also could rework and use something like *appointment*.

Comment: Please note that answers here are expected to be substantive, explanatory where appropriate, and written in standard English with standard punctuation and spelling - after all, it is an *English Language* site!

Answer (score 0):

Another (though unusual) option is to talk about a "*point in time*":

> Point in time of the event was January 10, 2010 3:15pm

But keep in mind the normal use of "*point in time*" is *to reference* a given date and time which was given befroe, like in:

> At *this* point in time all problems where solved.

Answer (score -1):

Your answer, is always the most concise description of a future "moment" yet to happen. However, time and place with meaning in the present, is only 1 thing: NOW.

And frankly, anything but NOW doesn't really matter. Yesterday is gone. Tomorrow may never come. For the NOW is all you really have.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? What word do you suggest as an answer?

Comment: "moment" - which has ties to the Greek word "atamos." There were other Greek words that also meant 'a moment in time;' however by using them you were already comparing that moment to others.

Comment: To say moment in ancient Greek, BC, and to do so without judgement. Where you only identified it as a point in time - the word was 'atamos' and I believe later in history 'atom' or 'atom in time' was derived that same way.